# How to Extract SubString between two positions

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression, substring

I have a text column (*emailbody*) in a table (*notification*) which keeps a record of the HTML that went out for a particular email. Somewhere inside that HTML file, there is a line of text that contains the following line:

```
Delayed ${shipmentId} for Carrier
```

Where `${shipmentId}` represents the specific Id that was generated for that particular record. Example: **12345**

Basically I want to query the column in the table for all the shipmentId values, which unfortunately will involve getting the string positions between `Delayed` and  `for Carrier`. I understand this will likely involve using one of Postgres' regular expression functions but I'm not quite sure how to do it, or if there's something a little simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SUBSTRING` function has [regex support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), so the following would work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(emailbody FROM 'Delayed (.*?) for Carrier') FROM notification
```

The so-called *capturing group* `()` is to make sure you capture only the shipment ID and not the entire string "Delayed 12345 for Carrier". The `?` makes the capture [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11898998/4751173), to make sure the first 'for Carrier' is matched.

Comment: Thanks, this almost works... except the "for Carrier (and everything following that) is still getting returned

Comment: Ah, a classic greedy regex. That's probably because you have another 'for Carrier' in the email body. Please try my updated version.

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm. Thanks so much!